# Performance string as function parameter

Tags: c++, string

I have function foo which get `std::string` as parameter:

```
void foo(std::string);
```

and I put a concatence string:

```
std::string str_1= "example_str_1";
std::string str_2 = "example_str_2";
foo(str_1+str_2);
```

It is a good way to use a concatence string with `std::move`?

```
foo(std::move(str_1+str_2));
```

Is there any difference between put concatence with `std::move`?

Answer (score 7):

No. The purpose of `std::move` is to cast to an rvalue, but `str_1+str_2` is already an rvalue, making the `move` call redundant.

The larger room for improvement here is in the signature of `foo` – why does it take a `std::string` by value? If it only observes the data, the real win here would be changing `foo` to `void foo(std::string const&)`, or use something akin to C++17's `std::string_view`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes of course with foo(std::string const&)

Comment: @M.S. : You're welcome. If you need to research value categories further, there's a lot of good information in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/636019).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference as `std::string` has a move constructor.

```
string (string&& str) noexcept;
```

> Acquires the contents of str. 
>  str is left in an unspecified but valid
>   state.

[Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)